# Como saber quantas vezes uma função foi executada?

Tags: javascript, funções

Existe algum modo de saber quantas vezes a seguinte função foi executada Ps: essa função é acionado ao click sobre o elemento.

```
function popBaloon (object) {
object.setAttribute("class", "hideBaloon");}
```

Gostaria de saber se há como criar uma função que conte quantas vezes a função acima foi executada.

Comment: Geralmente o pessoal cria uma variável para armazenar o valor da contagem.

Comment: Amigo se essa função está sendo chamada no click o elemento, então podemos dizer que você quer contar os clicks no elemento, logo basta criar uma função que incremente alguma variável e chamá-la no click do elemento..

Comment: Você pode contar os clicks através de uma variável:

Exemplo:

`javascript
<script type="text/javascript">var clicks = 0;</script>
<input value="Click" type="button" onclick="clicks++">
`

Comment: Tem várias formas de fazer isso, banco de dados, cookies, etc... Depende do que você quer fazer.